# Can I add animations on each image change using JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a slideshow of images that pull the images from the JavaScript array. I want to add an animation on change of each image. But they add to the image on load.

I have already tried `.animate({})` but it only applies to the image on load and does not get removed.

My JavaScript:

```
var i = 0;
var images = [];
var firstSlide = 0;
var time = 1000;

images[0] = 'michael-baird-14942-unsplash.jpg';
images[1] = 'kees-streefkerk-352781-unsplash.jpg';
images[2] = 'hakon-sataoen-1484216-unsplash.jpg';
images[3] = 'mario-silva-1492028-unsplash.jpg';
images[4] = 'will-turner-1474611-unsplash.jpg';

function changeImg() {
    if (i <= images.length && firstSlide == 0) {
      document.slide.src = images[i];
      if (i < images.length) {
        i++;
      } else if (i > 4) {
        document.slide.src = images[0];
      } else {
        i = 0;
      }
      setTimeout("changeImg()", time);
    }
  }

  $('.next').on('click', function() {
    firstSlide = 1;
    i++;
    var ind = (i % 5);
    document.slide.src = images[ind];
  });

  $('.prev').on('click', function() {
    firstSlide = 1;
    i--;
    var ind = (i % 5);
    document.slide.src = images[ind];
  });
  window.onload = changeImg;
```

My CSS:

```
.slideshow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 42px;
}

.slideshow img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 50%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 0px 10px 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}

.next:hover,
.prev:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.prev {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 50%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0px 10px 5px 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="slideshow">
      <img name="slide" alt="Slideshow Images" width="100%" height="100%" class="test">
      <a class="next">&#10095;</a>
      <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="masterjs.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
```

I would like there to be an animation when the image swaps to the next one. Example would be like fading in and out of each image to the next one or check out https://www.oakley.com their slideshow slides to the left or the right between each image.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of animation you want to make.

If you want to make slide animation (translation along X axis) you need to add several *img* tags in container and move container on every transition.

If you want fadeIn-fadeOut, you can:

```
$(document.slide).fadeOut("slow",function(){
   /* change image src here */ 
   $(document.slide).fadeIn("slow"); 
});
```

**UPDATE**

Slide animation (main idea)

HTML

```
<div class="slideshow">
      <div class="slides"></div>
      <a class="next">&#10095;</a>
      <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="masterjs.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

CSS

```
/* === new lines === */

.slideshow {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slides {
  white-space: nowrap; 
}

/* === === */

.slideshow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 42px;
}

.slideshow img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;  
}

.next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 50%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 0px 10px 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}

.next:hover,
.prev:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.prev {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 50%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0px 10px 5px 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var i = 0;
var images = [];
var time = 3000; //delay between transitions
var slides;
var timeout;

images[0] = 'michael-baird-14942-unsplash.jpg';
images[1] = 'kees-streefkerk-352781-unsplash.jpg';
images[2] = 'hakon-sataoen-1484216-unsplash.jpg';
images[3] = 'mario-silva-1492028-unsplash.jpg';
images[4] = 'will-turner-1474611-unsplash.jpg';

function changeImg( direction ) {

    if( direction == null || direction == 'toLeft' ){
        i < images.length - 1 ? i++ : i = 0; 
    }
    else {
        i > 1 ? i-- : i = images.length - 1; 
    }

    //move slides
    slides.css({
        transform: 'translate(-' + ( i*100 ) + '%)' 
    });

    /*
     clear timeout on every user click faster than time to stop auto moving
     if user didn't click timeout has time to call changeImg
    */
    clearTimeout( timeout ); 
    timeout = setTimeout( changeImg, time );  

}


$(function(){

    slides = $(".slides");

    slides.css({
        transition: ( time / 3) + 'ms' // ( time / 3 ) - animation duration 
    });

    images.forEach(
        function( image, index ){
           slides.append($('<img src="' + images[index] + '" />')); 
        }
    );


    $('.next').on('click', function() { changeImg('toLeft'); });
    $('.prev').on('click', function() { changeImg('toRight'); });

    changeImg();

});
```

Comment: I want it to mostly move to the left and the next image come in from the right like Oakley’s. I tried what you said above but ran into problems